# How to convert ISO Date to UTC date in Hive

Tags: date, hive, type-conversion, unix-timestamp, isodate

I have JSON data as below: I need to convert that date or `mongo_date` into utc timestamp, to analyse the data in hive as per timeline example per year, per month, per week using map reduce

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ac77050e9edcdad271ce2d"),
    "company" : null,
    "date" : "19760224",
    "mongo_date" : ISODate("1976-02-24T00:00:00Z")
```

Comment: Hi, have you found any workaround to use mongo_date with existing UDFs like Hour or Minutes? Because the Month, Week, and Day work with those UDFs but after 'T' it ignores the hh:mm:ssZ. tnx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hive understands this format: `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'`.

Use `unix_timestamp()` to convert to seconds passed from 1970-01-01, then use `from_unixtime()` to convert to proper format:

```
 select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2017-01-01T05:01:10Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Result:

```
2017-01-01 05:01:10
```

**Update.** This method is to remove `Z` and replace `T` with space using `regexp_replace` and convert to timestamp if necessary, without using `unix_timestamp()`, this will preserve milliseconds:

```
select timestamp(regexp_replace("2019-05-17T17:03:09.775Z", '^(.+?)T(.+?)Z$','$1 $2'));
```

Result:

```
2019-05-17 17:03:09.775
```