# Timestamp conversion in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to convert the following string value to timestamp in hive

2016-12-31T07:09:48.507Z --> 2016-12-31 07:09:48.507

Can you please advise me how can we do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520257/2700344

Comment: excellent. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help you to convert string into datetimestamp

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(REGEXP_REPLACE('2016-12-31T07:09:48.507S', 'T', ' '), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have milliseconds, unix_timestamp won't work. I think you need this

```
SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE('2016-12-31T07:09:48.507S', 'T|S', ' ') as timestamp) AS formatted_timestamp;
```

Output

```
formatted_timestamp
2016-12-31 07:09:48.507
```