# how to Convert String of format "dd-mmm-yy" to timstamp in hadoop?

Tags: hive

How do I get a string of format `dd-mmm-yy` eg. "26-FEB-19", into timestamp in hive? Cast isn't working as it only takes `yyyy-mm-dd` format

Answer (score 0):

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('26-FEB-19','dd-MMM-yy'))
```

Result:

```
2019-02-26 00:00:00
```

Read about format templates here:[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Similar question (different format): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49816456/2700344