# string to timestamp conversion in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a column which has strings in the following format:-

```
2019-11-30T18:21:43.4775456Z
```

How do I convert it to timestamp? If I use the following I get NULLs

```
select cast(mycolumn as timestamp)
```

So obviously we need to specify format somewhere, but it appears that cast won't accept 'format' and also I am not sure which format to specify for the kind of values my column has.

The goal is to be able to perform max operation on this column as part of `group by` , but if I do that without any conversion , obviously it won't make sense as these are strings.

Comment: surprisingly min and max are working accurately on this string format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520257/2700344 Max and min, order and groupby will work fine w strings if they are in sortable comparable format like yours.